# Host subdomain in external server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, subdomain, static-ip

I have the domain name creabienestar.com.mx and a web hosting for this domain with some company. At my office I have an ubuntu server with apache2 installed and I also have a static ip address.

My goal is to have the subdomain sacredi.creabienestar.com.mx point to my server at my office, but I don't know where to start. In fact what I want is to make accesible my server from the internet without buying an aditional domian name, that's why I'm asking how to use subdomains. It is possible to do that? What are your suggestions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a couple of steps.

1. First modify the DNS of creabienestar.com.mx and add:

   sacredi.creabienestar.com.mx IN A 11.22.33.44 *(replace 11.22.33.44 with your static IP)*
2. Then modify your router/firewall at your office to allow web traffic (port 80 & 443) to be tunneled to your ubuntu server.
3. Set up your Apache, LAMP, java app server etc to serve your web apps.
4. Extend further with email etc if needed.

Comment: Great I did like you told me and it works fine, but i still have a question. Right now this setup displays what is under /var/www/, but how do I display a specific folder (sacredi/) without putting that in the url? I mean, I want to access to sacredi/ directory with sacredi.creabienestar.com.mx  url instead sacredi.creabienestar.com.mx/sacredi, is this possible?

Comment: Use DocumentRoot setting in apache virtual host config file (in /etc/apache2/sites-available) to specify root folder

Answer (score 1):

You should check and see if your current registrar has a DNS control panel - most do. In that you need to create an A record for sacredi.creabienestar.com.mx that has your fixed IP address as a value.

You also need to ensure that whatever the device is that connects your office to your ISP will allow inbound connections on port 80 and that they are forwarded to your server.

Comment: Thanks @lain, do you know how to configure an apache2 virtual host to work with fixed ip or where to find it?

Comment: Do you need it to server different IPs or just one static IP. If just one, just accept all traffic by using * eg:<VirtualHost *:80>
 (All though that is a different question.